# useContext doesn't work when in same file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-context

So not sure if this is exactly the problem, but wondering why this is happening when using contexts in the same file vs different files.

So here is the constant:

#### StartupContext.js

```
import React from "react";

export const StartupContext = React.createContext()

export const StartupProvider = ({ something, children }) => {
    return (
        <StartupContext.Provider value={{ something }}>
            {children}
        </StartupContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

No problems there. But when I run this:

#### App.js

```
function Root() {
  const { something } = useContext(StartupContext);

  return (
    <Text>Root {something}</Text>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [something, setSomething] = useState("ayyyy")

  return (
    <StartupProvider something={something}>
      <Root />
    </StartupProvider>
  );
}
```

I'll get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Context._context')

**BUT**

If I split into two files

#### App.js

```
import { Root } from "./Root";

export default function App() {
  const [something, setSomething] = useState("ayyyy")

  return (
    <StartupProvider something={something}>
      <Root />
    </StartupProvider>
  );
}
```

#### Root.js

```
export default function Root() {
  const { something } = useContext(StartupContext);

  return (
    <Text>Root {something}</Text>
  )
}
```

It will work just fine. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh man. It was something totally different.

I was importing on the single file:

```
import StartupContext from "./app/contexts/startupContext";
```

which was wrong, what I should have had was this:

```
import { StartupContext } from "./app/contexts/startupContext";
```